# Error when open camera on Android 11 in Ionic-v1

Tags: ionic-framework, android-11, ionic-v1

I have an application that is in Ionic-v1, after I perform a last build there was an error where the camera on android doesn't open anymore. I detected that in lower versions it's working (10 .. 7) but in version 11 it just stopped working.
Has anyone gone through this or imagine what it could be?
I've tried to update the permissions for using the camera but without favorable results.

Comment: try to update your Plugin.

Comment: I even upgraded the plugin, but it didn't solve the situation either.